# Hive Managed vs External table for Updates and Inserts

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, hdfs, amazon-emr

What are the Pros and Cons of hive external and managed tables?

We want to do updates and inserts in Hive tables but wonder which approach to take for these (Managed tables or create a workaround with refreshing external tables after manual file updates), especially after adding many files over time.. Will one approach or the other become too slow (e.g. too many files/too many updates to track via metastore and therefore master node becomes slow?)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There are a number limitations to do DMLs on Hive. Please read the documentation link for more details - https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Hive+Transactions. It’s always recommend not to use DML on Hive managed tables especially if the data volume is huge or if the table grows in size over time these operations would become too slow. Although, these operations would be considerably faster if done on a partition/bucket instead of the full tables. Nevertheless it better to handle the edits in file and do a full refresh via external table and only use DML on managed tables as last resort.